# db2batch -w switch and import operation

Tags: batch-file, import, db2, blob, truncate

I am using db2 10.5 with fixpack 4.
What i try to achieve is to measure time of importing varius size of blob and measure their read time.
I am using table test with columns id of integer type and data of blob with length 2147483647.

Now to the point:
for measure reading i am using db2batch - works fine but... i keep getting cli that readed row was truncated. Currently biggest file in table has 12 MB and while running db2batch im using:
db2batch -d SAMPLE -a ADMINISTRATOR -f c:\batch.sql -r c:\results.txt -w 2147483647.
According to documentation -w is right thing to use if we want to specify how long row can be read but it doesnt seems to be working for me ;/

Second thing:
For import i am using command:
import from c:\import.dta of del lobs from c:\images modified by lobsinfile insert into administrator."test"

that command works fine in command line but while trying to use it in db2batch i get error regarding backslash.. so my question is - is there a way to "escape" this character so it will be processed by db2batch or is there any other way to make command like that work in db2batch?

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to test here. Are you trying to time how fast DB2 can insert rows with LOBs (i.e. since you mention using `import`)? Or are you testing how fast DB2 can pull rows with LOBs out of the database (because the `-w` switch for `db2batch` is there to specify how wide the output results can be when you select rows from a table).  Please clarify, or, better, post the SQL that you're trying to execute with `db2batch`.

Comment: Hey, well i am trying to achieve booth. Get time of how fast DB2 can insert rows with LOBs and second how fast can it read rows with LOBs.